# Are all skills affected by elemental damage increase?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3, all skills have an element assigned to them (physical, cold etc.). What I'm wondering is what happens if a skill does not do direct damage? For example: [Mantra of Conviction](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/mantra-of-conviction), [Inner Sanctuary](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/inner-sanctuary) with Forbidden Palace rune. They apply a debuff on enemies that makes them take x% additional damage.

Is there a general rule telling when elemental% applies and when it does not?

Comment: The skills you're mentioning don't do damage in any sense.  They just make monster take more damage from *other* skills.  Which do have elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elemental % applies to every skill.  If a skill does damage, it will have an element, and be affected by +Elemental damage of the correct type.

The skills you are specifically referring to have no element because they don't do damage.  All they do is make *other* skills do more damage, and will affect the skills used while enemies are under those debuffs.

Comment: I'll check the list of all skills and see if there are any shady ones.